# Capture date from Excel sheet with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, excel

I know capturing a date is usually a simple enough RegEx task, but I need this to be so specific that I'm struggling.

`1 SUSTAINABLE HARVEST SECTOR | QUOTA LISTING JUN 11 2013
2 QUOTA
3 TRADE ID    AVAILABLE STOCK    AMOUNT    PRICE
4 130196      COD GBW            10,000    $0.60
5 130158      HADDOCK GBE        300       $0.60`

That is what the beginning of my Excel spreadsheet looks like, and what 100's more look like, with the date and the data changing but the format staying the same.

My thoughts were to capture everything that follows `LISTING` up until the newline... then place the non numbers (`JUN`) in my Trade Month column, place the first captured number (`11`) in my Trade Day column, and place the last captured number (`2013`) in my Trade Year column... but I can't figure out how to. Here's what I have so far:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Listing(.+?)(?=\n)')
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        print("df is:", df)
        a = pattern.findall(str(df))
        print("a:", a)
```

but that returns nothing. Any help solving this problem, which I know is probably super simple, is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your expression case insensitive (ie `LISTING` != `Listing`):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Listing(.+?)(?=\n)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Besides, a lookahead for a newline in this situation comes down to the equal expression:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Listing(.+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

See your [**working pattern here**](https://regex101.com/r/pzQVuT/1).

Comment: Ok so that does what I asked perfectly, and I'll 'check off' your answer when I can in 7minutes. But while I have you here: now that I have captured `a: [' JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \\']` is it easy enough to now isolate and capture/export the `JUN`, `11`, and `2013` pieces individually?

Comment: Instead of regex, you can use `datetime.strptime` which will give you a datetime object, which understands what parts are months etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: @theprowler: It is [**possible**](https://regex101.com/r/pzQVuT/2) but as Alan points out, there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Ohhhhh damn I didn't even know you could do that. I thought since I didn't have a full month name that I couldn't do something like that since trying `parser.parse()` from `dateutil` failed. Thanks guys, I appreciate you helping a beginner like myself

Comment: Umm real quick: I got `ValueError: time data "[' JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \\\\']" does not match format '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'` when trying that `strptime()` function. Should I fix the RegEx to capture less, or alter the `%`s as the second argument?

Comment: @theprowler: Where does the `Unnamed` come from? Please post a follow-up question and link from here to it. Comments section is kind of nasty.

Comment: I just posted the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558338/trouble-using-datetime-strptime    Also, I'm not sure what `Unnamed` is or why it gets captured, it's not in the excel file