# Trouble using datetime.strptime()

Tags: python, regex, excel, datetime, strptime

I have an Excel spreadsheet. I am trying to capture a line from the Excel sheet that contains a date, then parse the date out with `datetime.strptime()`.

Here is the bit of the Excel sheet I'm working with:

[image]

and my relevant code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'Listing(.+)', re.IGNORECASE)

a = pattern.findall(str(df))
print("a:", a)

new_a = str(a)
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(new_a, '%b %w %Y')
print("date:", datetime_object)
```

So I capture everything that follows `LISTING` and produce:

`a: [' JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \\']`

Then I try to extract the `Jun`, `11`, and `2013` but I fail with:

`ValueError: time data "[' JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \\\\']" does not match format '%b %w %Y'`

I am fairly sure this is a simple fix but being a beginner I can't see how exactly to fix it. Should I alter my RegEx to capture less? Or should I fix the arguments that `date.strptime()` is taking in?

The arguments seem to be right when looking at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the regex you're using to get the date from the Excel file.

`pattern = re.compile(r'Listing ([A-Z]+ \d{1,2} \d{4})', re.IGNORECASE)`

`[A-Z]+` means "one or more capital letters", `\d{1,2}` means "one or two numbers" and `\d{4}` means "four numbers".

Furthermore the format of date you're using is incorrect - `%w` means weekday (numbers from 0 to 6 representing weekdays from Sunday to Saturday), while you should use `%d` which matches day of the month

So it should look like this in the end:
`datetime_object = datetime.strptime(new_a, '%b %d %Y')`

Comment: That failed with the same error: `ValueError: time data "[' JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \\\\']" does not match format ' %b %d %Y'`

Comment: I added the documentation for reference....my tags seem to be correct now but it still fails. Is that due to all the extra fluff in my string?

Comment: You are correct. I edited te answer. I hope everything is all right now and it works fine :)

Comment: It still fails. I have zero clue how because the RegEx worked absolutely perfect. I receive the error: `ValueError: time data "['JUN 11 2013']" does not match format '%b %d %Y'` which makes no sense at all because `%b` is for an abbreviated month such as `JUN`, `%d%` is for a day of the month in number form such as `11`, and `%Y` is for a year such as `2013`.

Comment: It makes sense, because `findall` returns a list and you try to match the list against the pattern. You need to get the first element of the list, which is the string that you want to get the date from.

Comment: Ohh ok. So what I did with `a` since it's a list, on the next line I turn it into a string and store that in `new_a`. Is that a bad method? Should I instead index the first `a` with `[0]` or something?

Comment: Yup I just captured the first element from the list instead of turning the list into a string and it worked and I was able to use `dateutil`'s `parser.parse()` to get the year, month, and day isolated. Thanks for all the very useful well explained help :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working and I'm glad I could help!